# Where do I go from Linear algebra past Calc III to try to learn complex physics (relativity and quantum group theory)?

Tags: physics, self-learning, quantum-groups, general-relativity

I'm mainly a **programmer**, but I have a love for Mathematics that's been, well, insatiable. I've had my eye on learning Quantum Groups and Relativity, but I want to stay in something I can do with **Computer Graphics**. What do I need to know?

I have got a **solid grasp of**:

1. Calc I,
2. Clac II
3. Some Calc III (basically 3D+ applications of single and multidimensional calculus).
4. Linear Algebra (for graphics programming)

I have a **decent grasp of:**

1. Abstract Algebra,
2. Set Theory
3. Binary Lattices (mostly from computer mathematics).

I do have a book on finite groups that is really interesting. However I have to admit, that other than knowing that in hyperbolic geometry sinx - cosx = 1 is nearly the extent of that subject.

So, what I think I'm asking is how to go from **where I'm at**, to get to the calculus of manifolds, riemannian geometry, so on.

**EDIT**: I think what I'm looking to do is mainly **Theoretical/Mathematical Physics**, specifically things that I can make into awesome **graphics** programs.

Comment: I heard good things about Michael Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds. Mainly that it's exceptionally difficult, but that it pays off greatly. Just throwing it out there.

Comment: What does Galois theory have to do with your problem? (Most of quantum mechanics and relativity do not require knowing Galois theory at all!)

Comment: How much exactly do you know about group theory? If its only a small amount, then I can't see it as being advisable to jump into Galois theory (and as the comment above says, it is largely independant of quantum mechanics, relativity, and physics in general - although groups still play a fairly massive role once you get deep enough)

Comment: @Adar Hefer, I have that book, I just don't understand it when I do a read over of it yet, probably will take a bit more of a closer look.

Comment: @Andrew D and Willie Wong. It seems every time I did a search on group theory and physics, Galois theory seemed to keep popping up in the search results, so I came to the assumption that it was needed.

Comment: @mathacka check out the index of the Amazon textbooks that come up when you Google group theory and physics-no Galois theory. Galois theory is most directly related to number theory, which is getting more connections to physics but isn't central for that purpose.

Comment: Your title also mentioned quantum groups. [They are quite different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group) from quantum mechanics. It will help if you clarified (edited the original question) a bit what exactly it is that you want to learn.